# Trigger python code at server side from client in Angular4

Tags: python, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular, I am building a simple application which should do.

1. Accept couple of parameters from web page(client side)
2. Upon form submit, it should trigger a python code at server side
3. Get the output file(jpg image) generated by python and display below the submit form.

As part of this, I have just coded the app.component.html and a blank python refresh module in app.component.ts, but I'm unable to

A. Code to call python code at server side and retrieve the output

Also, upon searching across many places, I got answers to get data from web api call but not executing a python at server side and retrieving data.

Any reference or a code to this will be really very helpful !

My app.component.html looks like

```
<form (submit)="pytrigger(parm1.value,parm2.value)">
  <div>
    <label for="parm1">Parm1:</label>
    <input type="text" #parm1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="parm2">Parm2:</label>
    <input type="text" #parm2>
  </div>
  <div >
    <input type="submit" class="button">
  </div>
</form>
```

My app.component.ts has function(which needs to be extended)

```
  pytrigger(parm1,parm2){
    console.log('entered pytrigger');

  }
```

Comment: We can't help you with such broad questions. You should try many things out and come back with a very specific question.

Comment: I have below codes of my app.component.html and app.component.ts, hope this may help to advice.